# Embedded an angular app into some Svelte pages

Tags: angular, sveltekit

Basically I have a showcase website build in Svelte (with SSR for SEO purpose),
and on the other side I have a simple NG SPA app.
I want to include this app in some pages of my former Svelte website.
Is there a good way to perform that goal?

I just think of include cdn dist NG files into incriminate pages which own an  tag. Is that the good approach?